# What does the map function in the Applicative from Category theory do?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, category-theory

Given the following statement about functional programming - in particular reasoning about category theory - [we see](https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/applicative/Applicative.scala) the `map` function inside the `Applicative`.

```
trait Applicative[F[_]] extends Functor[F] {
  def map2[A,B,C](fa: F[A], fb: F[B])(f: (A, B) => C): F[C] =
    apply(map(fa)(f.curried))(fb)
...
```

My question is: **What does the map function in the Applicative from Category theory do?**

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. The map function in Applicative does exactly the same thing it does in Functor. Are you asking what it does inside the definition of map2? In map2 you apply a function of two arguments called f to two containers fa and fb. First you curry f, to get a function of one argument that returns a function. You apply this curried function to fa using map. It produces a container of functions of one argument. You apply this container of functions to the second container fb using "apply".

Comment: Bartosz, it’s an honour to have you comment on this question. Thanks for being to helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's defined just a few lines after `map2`, using only `apply` and `unit`:

```
def map[A,B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B] = apply(unit(f))(fa)
```

You can plug in the definition of `map` into `map2` and thereby obtain a definition of `map2` that relies only on `apply` and `unit`:

```
def map2[X, Y, Z](x: F[X], y: F[Y])(f: (X, Y) => Z): F[Z] = 
  apply(apply(unit((x: X) => (y: Y) => f(x, y)))(x))(y)
```

Therefore, `map` is not required to define `map2` from `apply` and `unit`, because it itself can be derived from `apply` and `unit`.

It behaves just like `map` of any other `Functor` (because every `Applicative` is automatically a `Functor`): given an `F[A]` and an `f: A => B`, it produces an `F[B]`.